# How to cancel previous ES request before making a new one

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using NodeJS with https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch package

Use Case is like this: When a link is clicked on the page, I will make a request to NodeJS Server which will in turn use the ES node package to fetch the data from ES Server and sends the data back to the client.

The issue is, when two requests are made in quick session(two links clicked in a short span), the Response of first request and then the Response of second request is reaching the client. The UI depends on this response, and i would like to directly show only the second request's response.

So, the question is, Is there any way to cancel out the previous request made to ES Server before starting a new one ?

Code:
ES Client:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'HostName',
    log: 'trace'
});
```

Route:
`app.get('/data/:reportName', dataController.getReportData);`

DataController:

```
function getReportData(req, res) {
    query = getQueryForReport(report)
    client.search(query)
        .then(function(response) {
            res.json(parseResponse(response)
     })
}
```

So, the same API `/data/reportName` is called twice in succession with different reportNames. I would like to send only the second report Data back and cancel our the first request.

Comment: Folks here could help you a lot better if you showed the client code you are using.  Once a request has been sent to a server, you can't really cancel it (Ajax has an abort, but the server is probably already off doing it's thing processing the request).  But, you can handle the responses and make sure you only process the latest response when more than one are in flight at a given time.  How to do that is specific to your code which is why we could help better if we could see your actual code.

Comment: Its best not to abort server side calls once initiated. Your best bet is implement a mechanism to handle simultaneous calls at the client side itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about the UX, rather than stressing your ES, than `aborting` the ajax request is what you want.

Since you didn't post your client side code, I'll give you a generic example:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "searching_route",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Remember that aborting the request may not prevent the `elasticsearch` query from being processed, but will prevent the client from receiving the data.